# How to make an UITextView scrollable when the keyboard appears?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, scroll, uitextview

I would like to know how I can make my `UITextView` scrollable when it's being edited ? When the user wants to edit it, the keyboard shows but then the `UITextView` is no more scrollable. So all the text behind the keyboard is not visible.

Comment: Change the size of the scroll view that it is not behind the keyboard anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce sizeOf you textView on keyBoard appear

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frame = txtAddNote.frame;
    frame.size.height = 150; //Decrease your textView height at this time
    txtAddNote.frame = frame;
}
-(IBAction)DoneBarBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = txtAddNote.frame;
    frame.size.height = 212; //Original Size of textView
    txtAddNote.frame = frame;

    //Keyboard dismiss 
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just scroll the view when `UITextView` begin edit like this..

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, -160, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

and in endEditing just set Default screen like bellow..

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here with your requirement we set the frame with our view see bellow code

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
         [yourTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.‌​frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height - 160)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [yourTextView setFrame:self.view];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: No this doesn't work at all. I have a toolbar at the top with a 'back' button and a 'done' button. Then I have an UITextView that is almost as big as the view itself. So when I do your method, the view just move up, and then the toolbar is no more reachable. And to finish , this doesn't make my UITextView scrollable whereas I selected the scrollable options in the IB, and I can scroll it when I'm not editing it.

Comment: @frénésie just add this line and test it..         [yourTextView setScrollsToTop:YES];

Comment: and also     [textView setScrollEnabled:YES]; try this

Comment: Ok so my UITextView is scrollable when the keyboard is shown. What I would like to do is scroll this UITextView when the text starts to be behind the keyboard. And then keep scrolling as long as the user type more and more text.

Comment: its automatically go where you text entered and also here if you want to see the text which you enter then just setFrame of textview when this in edit mode and set default when it end editing this is simple idea for it..

Comment: in edit mode write this [yourTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height - 160]; and when return from editing mode st like this [yourTextView setFrame:self.view];