# How to scroll `UITextView` programmatically when user enters each line?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

How can I scroll my `UITextView` programmatically when user enters each line.

It is necessary for my textView since keypad hides it at some point as shown below.
[image]

I searched lot, but didn't found any appropriate solution, as I am a newbie to iPhone development. I need your valuable help.

Comment: you have to change the frame of the view while keyboard show and hide....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701478/how-to-make-an-uitextview-scrollable-when-the-keyboard-appears/13702111#13702111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you are opening the keyboard, you should adjust the frame of your textview. In this case reduce the height of your frame by the height of keyboard.

Implement proper code for these two delegate methods.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGRect frm = textView.frame;
    frm.height -= KEY_BOARD_HEIGHT;
    textView.frame = frm;
}
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
{
    CGRect frm = textView.frame;
    frm.height += KEY_BOARD_HEIGHT;
    textView.frame = frm;
}
```

Comment: thanx buddy!  but i cant find height value for CGRect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701478/how-to-make-an-uitextview-scrollable-when-the-keyboard-appears/13702111#13702111

Answer (score 1):

Take a variable for Scrolling position :: **`int scrollY;`**

Code for **TextView** ::

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        scrollY += 10;
        scrMain.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, scrollY);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Then, when user resign from keyboard, set it to again 0 and scroll to its origin position.

```
scrollY = 0;
scrMain.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

Hope, it may help you.

Thanks.

Comment: its scrollview.. so it'll set offset little bit upper.

Comment: @mvp: I hope you understand, whenever user press return key or enter key, it'll increase size and set offset as user interact. this way it'll be helpful.

Comment: why the method is not called even when my textview entered return key or enter key..? one thing.. i have three textviews there..

Comment: did you set delegate with textview ??

Comment: if you three delegates then check with if(textview == YOUR_TEXTVIEW) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` scroll text automatically when enter text, you only change `UITextView` frame to above keyboard and when you dismiss key board reset `UITextView` frame

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   //set frame for text view here
}
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  //set frame for text view here
}
```