# Keyboard covering UITextView in Notes App

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Hi guys I am making a notes app and I ran into a big problem. I am using a UITextView as the notepad. When the keyboard comes up it blocks some of the text in the UITextView. I have a input accessory view on the UITextView. I tried to find the answer in the internet and can not find a good answer.Any way to fix it? Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701478/how-to-make-an-uitextview-scrollable-when-the-keyboard-appears/13702111#13702111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to subtract the UITextView height by the keyboard height:

```
NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
kbSIZE = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.notesTextView.frame;
newTextViewFrame.size.height -= kbSIZE.size.height;
newTextViewFrame.size.height += self.notesTextView.inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height;
self.notesTextView.frame = newTextViewFrame;
```

Comment: here is same thing i did in past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701478/how-to-make-an-uitextview-scrollable-when-the-keyboard-appears/13702111#13702111

Comment: I would advise against this as the keyboard in iOS 7 is translucent. You need to be able to see the content scroll under the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at modifying the UITextView's contentOffset and contentInset. UITextField is a UIScrollView subclass after all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` to the `UIEdgeInsets` of the keyboard height. The `contentInset` value makes the scrolling height taller, but allows you to still scroll content under the keyboard. The `scrollIndicatorInsets` makes the scroll indicators stop at the bottom of the keyboard.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);

    self.textView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```